# My login php script that redirects to each user page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have login system where diffrent users can login

when user A is logging in it redirect to home.php

when user B is logging in it redirect to home.php

How make each user login to their own page

like facebook redirect

when i log in it shows my information and my posts

when my friend login it shows his information and his posts

Comment: So what are you expecting from SO?

Comment: what about they all login in one page , and page will full with their information?

Comment: hi lal i want make each user to login to their accout information but my login system when A user login it taking to home,php and when B login it taking to home.php  how make when user login it show thier information and their image(profile pic

Comment: when people login it should redirect to their accout information and their own page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are wanting to use Query Strings. There are plenty of resources online to help you out. Here are some examples:

https://lightignite.com/help-your-customers-fill-out-web-forms-with-url-query-strings/
http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/tutoring/soen287/tutorials/query-strings-and-forms/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a login system management. You need to have good understanding of php before diving into learning login systems. Else CMS like wordpress offers plenty of tools and plugins for easy login authentication system without any serious programming.

Secondly, you can target using frameworks such as laravel, yii, symfony,codeignitor. They let you make develop such demanding systems faster and more customized.

Before you do a very basic implementation of login system, understand how much hard it is to protect them. Knowing the vulnerabilities is important.

Comment: Hi sachin i want devleop login system when user login it redirect to the users account details  and asked user to upload some images next time if he login it must show his account details and previous upload details

Comment: But in my case it is logging in same homepage.php for every user who logging in

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what actually CMS with login system or frameworks with login scripts do. If you have enough skills in PHP to understand structured queries and classes, i would recommend using frameworks, else you can use wordpress for very easy implementation about this. Its so easy, it can be done in half an hour(while entire life would be spent to make that code optimized for corporates). Though it can be good for starting at something.